# Return json Hierarchical structure in single SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, hierarchical-data

I need to create a SQL query (postgres 9.5.3) which returns a hierarchical json result. This is the code I wrote so far

```
WITH RECURSIVE q AS ( 
    WITH c AS (
        SELECT pc."Id", pc."Description"
        FROM "ProductCategories" pc 
        WHERE pc."Active" = true 
    )
    SELECT pc, ARRAY[c] as "Children", ARRAY[pc."Id"] as "Path" 
    FROM "ProductCategories" pc 
    LEFT JOIN c ON pc."Id" = c."Id"
    WHERE NULLIF(pc."ParentId", 0) IS NULL 
    AND pc."Active" = true 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT pc_descendant, array_append(q."Children", c), q."Path" || pc_descendant."Id" 
    FROM q 
    JOIN "ProductCategories" pc_descendant ON pc_descendant."ParentId" = (q.pc)."Id" 
    LEFT JOIN c ON pc_descendant."Id" = c."Id"
    WHERE pc_descendant."Active" = true 
)
SELECT * FROM q
```

I have problem to create hierarchical object `Children`. For these structure

```
A
    B
        C
D
    E
```

the `array_append` functions seems to append any children elements into single array:

```
A.Children = [ {B}, {C}, {D} ]    //for category A
```

I need structure:

```
  A.Children = [ {B, Children = [ {C, Children = [ {D} ] } ] } ]
```

How can I change my query to achieve this?
Regards

Answer (score 7):

Not sure that it is possible at least in the simple convenient way.

However it seems that it is simple using "true" recursion.

Here is simple example:

```
create temp table t(id int, parent int, name text) on commit drop;

insert into t values
  (1,null,'john'),
  (2,1,'jane'),
  (3,1,'jack'),
  (4,2,'julian');

create or replace function build_family(p_parent int) returns setof jsonb as $$

  select
    case 
      when count(x) > 0 then jsonb_build_object('name', t.name, 'family', jsonb_agg(f.x))
      else jsonb_build_object('name', t.name)
    end
  from t left join build_family(t.id) as f(x) on true
  where t.parent = p_parent or (p_parent is null and t.parent is null)
  group by t.id, t.name;

$$ language sql;


select jsonb_pretty(build_family) from build_family(null::int);
```

and result is

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────┐
│             jsonb_pretty             │
├──────────────────────────────────────┤
│ {                                   ↵│
│     "name": "john",                 ↵│
│     "family": [                     ↵│
│         {                           ↵│
│             "name": "jane",         ↵│
│             "family": [             ↵│
│                 {                   ↵│
│                     "name": "julian"↵│
│                 }                   ↵│
│             ]                       ↵│
│         },                          ↵│
│         {                           ↵│
│             "name": "jack"          ↵│
│         }                           ↵│
│     ]                               ↵│
│ }                                    │
└──────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I hope that you can adapt it for your data.

Good luck.

Comment: This is brilliant - love this elegant solution which really shows off the power of PostgreSQL!  I also updated the `'family', jsonb_agg(f.x)` to `'family', case when jsonb_agg(f.x) != '[null]'::jsonb then jsonb_agg(f.x) else '[]'::jsonb end` which returns ` ... `"family": [] ...` instead of ` ... `"family": [null] ...`.

Comment: @bobmarksie It depends in requirements IMO. Additionally to your suggestion I'v updated the answer to remove unnecessary empty "family" key at all.

Comment: Hi, can someone, in this case, one will happen in the first and second recursive loop.

Comment: Is this possible, to rewirte in CTE ? (just for understanding on this query).

Comment: @JongzPuangput No, it is impossible. Function uses the table and calling recursively itself. Doing all of this in the single statement is impossible. PS Sorry for the late answer.

Comment: I think this should be doable with a recursive CTE. But I have struggled with the CTE solution and couldn't get rid of some duplicates. Your solution is very neat, and much easier to understand than the CTE. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same Problem, but with whole rows. While solving it, I found an optimized version of the Idea:

```
create table fam(id int, parent int, name text) ;

insert into fam values
  (1,null,'john'),
  (2,1,'jane'),
  (3,1,'jack'),
  (4,2,'julian');

create or replace function build_family(p_parent int) returns setof jsonb as $$

  select jsonb_build_object('name', fam.name)
         ||jsonb_strip_nulls(
                  jsonb_build_object('family', (select jsonb_agg(build_family) from build_family(fam.id)))
            )
  from fam 
  where fam.parent = p_parent or (p_parent is null and fam.parent is null);

$$ language sql;


select jsonb_pretty(build_family) from build_family(null::int);
```

Result:

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "family": [
        {
            "name": "jane",
            "family": [
                {
                    "name": "julian"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "jack"
        }
    ]
}
```